# Stored procedure in a function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can we execute a stored procedure in a function?

Comment: no, We cant call store procedure in function.

Comment: @Valli Yes you can, but in a tricky way you probably shouldn't. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes. You can execute a stored proc in a function

CREATE FUNCTION tEsts (@id INT = null)
returns INT
AS
BEGIN 
EXEC  ca_CalcTRI
Return 1
END

Comment: Can we pass a parameter for executing stored procedure in function?